# XML schema validation: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a

Tags: xml, schema

I'm trying to validate my XML document against my XML schema.

This is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://cars.example.org/">
  <element name="cars">
    <complexType>
      <sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="brand" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

and this is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars xmlns="http://cars.example.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://cars.example.org/ cars.xsd">
  <brand>x</brand>
</cars>
```

Now when I'm validating the document (via Eclipse) I get following message on line 4:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'brand'. One of '{"":brand}' is expected.
```

This message doesn't make any sense :(. And it's very hard (impossible?) to google solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your schema is defining "brand" as being in no namespace. That's what `'{"":brand}'` means. But in your XML document the "brand" element is in the `http://cars.example.org/` namespace. So they don't match and you get your validation error.

To declare the "brand" element in your schema as being in the `http://cars.example.org/` namespace, add the attribute `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the schema element.

I suggest that for completeness you also add `attributeFormDefault="unqualified"` to the schema element, although that is not your problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have not validated the attribute within cars, which is the url of the namespace, this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
  targetNamespace="http://cars.example.org/">
  <element name="cars">
    <complexType>
      <sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="brand" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
       <attribute name="schemaLocation" type="anyURI"/>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:cars xmlns:my="http://cars.example.org/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://cars.example.org/ cars.xsd">
        <brand>x</brand>
</my:cars>
```

Your elementFormDefault in the schema is "unqualified", see: https://www.xfront.com/HideVersusExpose.html